# MySQL load data infile ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, syntax

I am using MySQL version 5.5 and I am trying to use load data infile and I am getting errors.  I've looked at the documentation and it looks like I am doing exactly what the docs specify.

Running this command in mysql

```
LOAD DATA local infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' 
INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Gives the following error.

> ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Running the following command

```
LOAD DATA local-infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' 
INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Gives the following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TER' at line 1

What is wrong with my syntax?
The data in the file is

```
126,126text,moretext
127,127text,moretext
```

Comment: Why dows you use `LOCAL`? does your client works with remote MySQL, and source file is local for client and remote for server really? Check does `LOAD FILE LOCAL` allowed both on server and on cilent side either by proper settings in INI file or by proper command line options.

Comment: for security reasons I am trying to use the above command.  I could set load local in the `ini` file but that could lead it issues.

Comment: Is Raspberry Pi involved?

Comment: Yes I am using a raspberry pi 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CLIENT SIDE

Before you run this

```
LOAD DATA local infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' 
INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

You need to start mysql client program with [`--local-file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile)

```
mysql --local-file -uroot -p
```

If you wish to have this configured permanantly, add this to `~/.my.cnf`

```
[mysql]
local-infile
```

This forces the mysql client program to execute.

## SERVER SIDE

The mysqld (server side must be started with [local_infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile)) in its `my.cnf` or `my.ini`.

Make sure to add this

```
[mysqld]
local_infile=1
```

and run

```
service mysql restart
```

If you cannot config it and restart it, login to mysql and run

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.local_infile;
```

or

```
mysql> SHOW GLOABL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

If you get `0`, you cannot execute `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` no matter what you do to the client side.

## SUPPLEMENTAL INFO

Running the following command

```
LOAD DATA local-infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' 
INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Gives the following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TER' at line 1

That's just a straight up syntax error.

Get rid of the dash between `local` and `infile` so that it reads

```
LOAD DATA local infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' 
INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: The ` @@global.local_infile` is `1`.  Tried `LOAD DATA local-infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`.  I am getting the same error `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`. If i use `local-infile` I get `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-infile '/home/pi/Downloads/load_data_infile.txt' INTO TABLE test_tbl FIELDS TER' at line 1`

Comment: I mentioned already at the bottom of my post : `That's just a straight up syntax error.`. Please Get rid of the dash between `local` and `infile`.

Comment: In my original post I did. I just tried again and I get the same error. `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Comment: Not sure but now it is working.  I added `local-infile=1` to my `.my.cnf` file restarted mysql but notihng.  Added it back to `.my.cnf` then rebooted the machine and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. That’s why I gave both client side and server side. Once you did both, things worked.